Uneven color noise on prints from Epson ET-8550
The prints on my ET-8550 have noise regardless of the printing quality i choose. I tried various quality settings, but the basic issue remains and seems to be related to uneven transport.
I've made two example prints in 15x10cm format. The prints were started on the printer itself from USB storage. Then scanned at 600 dpi where the noise is readily apparent. Please have a look at the scan here: https://wolkig.ch/index.php/s/bLokMS9TfJym5m6
The bottom print was made using "standard" quality, the upper print was made with "ultra glossy" setting. Both prints are on Epson Glossy Photo Paper.

Observe how the left and right borders have much less noise for about 1 cm. This is the beginning and end of the print, where the printing happens slower. This is why I assume the transport is not performing well, because when the printer slows down, the noise is muted and the quality is better.
Three times I've performed print head adjustment horizontally and vertically but the noise level did not change.
Is this noise level expected? Is there something I should try or is my unit defective and needs servicing under warranty?

Epson ET-8550 uses six inks.
To get other (i.e. "all") colors it may need to use a matrix of (e.g. 6 by 6) dots to simulate tones in between the actual inks.
One way to achieve that is "dithering":
https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/digital-camera-pixel.htm
...  which introduces "noise" or "grain" depending on how you view the result.
The differing edges may well be a side effect, created by the software this printer uses.
I'd recommend reading up on digital image basics:
https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/learn-photography-concepts.htm
